# How may I share a variable between a view and a controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, view, controller

I have a controller named Home, that sets @cars to be showed in the view:

```
def show
    authorize Car
    @cars = policy_scope(Car)
 end
```

But in the view i have a variable named current_season, and i need to show just the cars that were sold in the current season. Something like that:

```
car.rb (model)


def sample(current_season)
  car.sold_month == season ? true : false
end
```

I'm currently calling the method sample in the view and filtering, but i need to do this filter in the controller and i don't know how to pass the current_season variable. Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming it's a `GET` request, How about passing a URL parameter?

Comment: You pass the `current_season` variable from the controller to the view (not vice-versa) along with the filtered cars. And the controller probably gets the season from the user via an URL parameter or a form submission.

Comment: Thank you. I did set the variable in the controller.